# Arguments in the destructor for an environment

Tags: environments, arguments, bugs

The `\newenvironment` command allows the environment to take arguments:

```
\begin{article}
\newenvironment{preecho}[1]{#1}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{preecho}{Hi!}\end{preecho} % => Hi!
\end{document}
```

However, this argument cannot be accessed in the destructor:

```
\begin{article}
\newenvironment{postecho}[1]{}{#1} % => Illegal parameter number #1 in definition of \endpostecho.
\begin{document}
\begin{postecho}{Hi!}\end{postecho}
\end{document}
```

The error message makes it clear *why* this is happening.  However:

1. Is this behaviour intentional?
2. Is there a `\newenvironment`-type command that makes the argument accessible in the destructor?

Comment: Yes, it's the documented behavior. You can use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` instead, but the argument should be specified differently: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{echo}{m}{}{#1}`

Comment: @egreg, thanks!  Which package provides [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631130/arguments-in-the-destructor-for-an-environment#comment1573841_631130)?

Comment: No package, if you have LaTeX released on 2020-10-01 or later.

Comment: OK, [thanks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631130/arguments-in-the-destructor-for-an-environment#comment1573843_631130)!  So I should have said differently:  where is the syntax documented?  Also, since your [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631130/arguments-in-the-destructor-for-an-environment#comment1573841_631130) clearly answers the question, would you be willing to post it as an answer, or is it better if I close the question?

Comment: Answer to myself: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631130/arguments-in-the-destructor-for-an-environment#comment1573841_631130) functionality is provided by [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse).